# How to get the Windows username of the page visitor with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I've searched all around but I'm not coming up with anything, so I'm sorry if this is post is a dupe, I couldn't find any.

I've written this pretty extensive webapp for my company. The only thing that's left is to add some sort of auditing. I can't figure out how to capture the username of the person currently accessing my pages. Since the box this is hosted on is logged in as administrator, that's what I get as a return with functions like getpass.getuser() and os.environ("USERNAME").

Here's what I'm trying to do:

User access a webpage of mine
Grab username and do stuff with it behind the scenes.

Is there anyway I can do this with Flask? Or even Javascript?

EDIT:

I guess I wasn't clear. Apologies. I have a WebApp (written in Python using Flask as a web framework. I have written the webpages in Flask, HTML, CSS, and Javascript.) This Webpapp is hosted on a server. I want the username of the user access the page, not the user that's logged into the server. getpass.getuser() and os.environ.get("USERNAME") only returns administrator. Which is the server, not the user.

Comment: Did you want to get the username of the *visitor* or of the account running your Flask webserver? `os.environ("USERNAME")` returns the latter.

Comment: use os.environ.get("USERNAME") instead of os.environ("USERNAME")

Comment: @odaialghamdi: to do *what* exactly? The OP hasn't stated that that threw an exception..

Comment: There is nothing related to either flask or javascript in this question.

Comment: Is it that you want to know the username of the person logged in to some workstation that is on the same network as the webserver, and then this user is accessing your application using a browser? You want to know this _without having the user logon to your application_?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes. That's exactly what I want. I want to grab the windows username of a user accessing my page on the same internal network.

Comment: Try your luck with `AUTH_USER` in the request variables; but this not guaranteed to work nor is it reliable. You really need to let the users login if you want to know who is accessing your application.