# How do I get the username of the current user in a Flask app on an IIS server using Windows Authentication?

Tags: python, iis, flask, windows-authentication

I have a Flask app (Python 2.7) running on an IIS server in Windows 10. The server is configured to use Windows Authentication. I am using an HttpPlatformHandler in order to execute the Python code.

I have verified that the authentication is working and am able to see the Kerberos "Negotiate" auth header. However, I cannot find a way to access the username of the user who requested the page.

I have tried printing the entire request header and request environment and it is not there. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412852/flask-python-decoding-username-ntlm-or-negotiate-authentication-header) seems to be about my issue but the code in it is not correct. **What can I do to pass the Windows username of the requester to my python code?**

I would like to access the username of the user in order to both restrict page access by user and remove certain elements from pages based on user.

Comment: Reading this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894782/get-windows-username-with-flask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347412/rails-app-remote-user-attribute-in-iis-8-5-with-windows-authentication) works for my configuration as well. I simply downloaded ISAPI_Rewrite 3, copy and pasted the text into httpd.conf, and was able to access the name of the user by calling `request.headers.get('X-Remote-User')` in my Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using os library

```
import os

username = os.getlogin()
```

Answer (score -1):

If the user is logged in, you can use flask_login.current_user.name to get the info.