# How to get the username of the current user logged in a Flask app running on an Apache server?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, apache, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app (using Python version 3.7) running on an Apache server (version 2.4), using mod_wsgi (version 4.6.4), and SQLAlchemy (1.2.11).

I am working on designing a logic where I want to get the name of the manager of the current user logged in on Windows:

(Using get pass module with getuser method).

My query:

```
get_manager_name = session.query(Table.employee_first_name + " " + Table.employee_last_name).filter(Table.employee_net_username == getpass.getuser()).all()
```

The above query works if I bypass Apache (using the development server that comes with Flask).

On the other hand, If I use Apache, then the query returns an empty list `[]`.

I debugged my code using logging module in Python `(logging.debug(getpass.getuser()))` and found that `getpass.getuser()` returns the name of the service account under which Apache is running on my end and not the username of the current user logged in.

So my question is what I need to do to get the username of the logged in user through Apache on Windows?

I found a similar question on the similar issue, but it was related to IIS:

[How do I get the username of the current user in a Flask app on an IIS server using Windows Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627947/how-do-i-get-the-username-of-the-current-user-in-a-flask-app-on-an-iis-server-us)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Python get the username in windows and then implement it in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654122/how-to-make-python-get-the-username-in-windows-and-then-implement-it-in-a-script)

Comment: Does not work. It gives the username of the service account under which Apache is running.
I have even tried os.environ['USERNAME']
It prints the username of the logged in user if I bypass Apache.
Under apache, it prints the service account under which Apache is running.

Comment: I _think_ you'll need Kerberos authentication for this and some kind of security configuration on the browser.

Comment: Did you try `request.environ['REMOTE_USER']` ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a need to set up a middleware so that the logged in user's username can be sent to Flask app from Apache.

Was able to resolve by following:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/69/